# Python - Retrieving last 30 days data from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe containing six month error logs, collected every day. I want to retrieve the last 30 days records from the last date. Last date isn't today.
For example: I've data for the months May, June, July and until `August 15`, I want to retrieve that data from `August 15` to `July 15` making it 30 days records.
Is there a way to do this in Python Pandas?

This is the sample dataframe:

```
Error_Description         Date        Weekend      Type
N17739 Limit switch X-    5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Critical
N17739 Limit switch Y-    5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Critical
N938 Key non-functional   5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Non-Critical
P124 Magazine is running  5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Non-Critical
N17738 Limit switch Z+    5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Critical
N938 Key non-functional   5/1/2015    5/3/2015    Non-Critical
     ...                    ...         ...          ...
P873 ENCLOSURE DOOR       8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Non-Critical
N3065 Reset M114          8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Non-Critical
N3065 Reset M114,         8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Non-Critical
N2853 Synchronization     8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Critical
P152 ENCLOSURE            8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Non-Critical
N6236 has stopped         8/24/2015   8/30/2015   Critical
```

Comment: You can just slice the df `df.iloc[::30]` no?

Comment: @EdChum probably you mean `df.iloc[-30:]`?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov op wants to generate 30 day blocks so it depends, `df.iloc[-30:] takes just the last 30 entries

Comment: It gives me every 30th value from the dataframe beginning from 0. Also, in a day there are at least 1k error messages captured.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov - The output was last 30 records while I'm interested in last 30 days data. As I mentioned, there are multiple records in a single day

Comment: @EdChum - It gives me every 30th value from the dataframe beginning from 0. Also, in a day there are at least 1k error messages captured.

Comment: Could you attach piece of your dataframe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Date `lastdayfrom` is used for selecting last 30 days of `DataFrame` by function [loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
lastdayfrom = pd.to_datetime('8/24/2015')
print lastdayfrom
#2015-08-24 00:00:00

print df
#           Error_Description       Date    Weekend          Type
#0     N17739 Limit switch X- 2015-05-01 2015-05-03      Critical
#1     N17739 Limit switch Y- 2015-05-01 2015-05-03      Critical
#2    N938 Key non-functional 2015-05-01 2015-05-03  Non-Critical
#3   P124 Magazine is running 2015-05-01 2015-05-03  Non-Critical
#4     N17738 Limit switch Z+ 2015-02-01 2015-05-03      Critical
#5    N938 Key non-functional 2015-07-25 2015-05-03  Non-Critical
#6        P873 ENCLOSURE DOOR 2015-07-24 2015-08-30  Non-Critical
#7           N3065 Reset M114 2015-07-21 2015-08-21  Non-Critical
#8          N3065 Reset M114, 2015-08-22 2015-08-22  Non-Critical
#9      N2853 Synchronization 2015-08-23 2015-08-30      Critical
#10            P152 ENCLOSURE 2015-08-24 2015-08-30  Non-Critical
#11         N6236 has stopped 2015-08-24 2015-08-30      Critical

print df.dtypes
#Error_Description            object
#Date                 datetime64[ns]
#Weekend              datetime64[ns]
#Type                         object
#dtype: object

#set index from column Date
df = df.set_index('Date')
#if datetimeindex isn't order, order it
df= df.sort_index()

#last 30 days of date lastday
df = df.loc[lastdayfrom - pd.Timedelta(days=30):lastdayfrom].reset_index()
```

```
print df
#        Date      Error_Description    Weekend          Type
#0 2015-07-25       N3065 Reset M114 2015-08-21  Non-Critical
#1 2015-08-22      N3065 Reset M114, 2015-08-22  Non-Critical
#2 2015-08-23  N2853 Synchronization 2015-08-30      Critical
#3 2015-08-24         P152 ENCLOSURE 2015-08-30  Non-Critical
#4 2015-08-24      N6236 has stopped 2015-08-30      Critical
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DataFrame.last_valid_index()` to find the label of the last line, and then subtract `DateOffset(30, 'D')` to go back 30 days:

```
df[df.last_valid_index()-pandas.DateOffset(30, 'D'):]
```

Comment: (assuming the index is a DatetimeIndex...)

Comment: It is not clear which is the index in your example, but to use the solution I proposed above you need to set the column Date as index:
df2 = df.reset_index().set_index('Date')

Answer (score 6):

The other two answers (currently) assume the date is the index, but in python3 at least, you can solve this with just simple masking (`.query(..)` doesn't work).

`df[df["Date"] >= (pd.to_datetime('8/24/2015') - pd.Timedelta(days=30))]`